# Can I use comparison and logical operators for time inputs in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a site that assigns you a random number and random start time based on your age and time of registration.
a. If you are below 18 and you registered before 7:30 AM, you will be assigned a random number above 1000 and you will start at 9:30 AM.
b. If you are below 18 and you registered from 7:31 AM to 9:00 AM, you will get a random number below 1000 and you will start at 11:00 AM.
c. If you are below 18 and you registered from 9:01 AM onwards, you will get a random number below 1000 and you will start at 12:30 AM.

Can I use if else statements to compare the times of registration submitted by the users (ex. registrationTime > 7:30)? If not, is there another way?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <title>Race Day</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Race Day</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="http://pixelartmaker-data-78746291193.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/image/486628a7f81e711.png" alt="runner">
        </div>
        <div class="form-wrapper" id="form-wrapper">
        <form action="#">
            <label for="fullName">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="fullName" id="fullName" autocomplete="off" required>
            <label for="age">Age</label>
            <input type="number" name="age" id="age" min="1" max="100" required>
            <label for="time">Time of Registration</label>
            <input type="time" name="time" id="time" required>
            <button id="myBtn" type="button" onclick="save()">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
        <div class="raceNumberContainer">
            <p id="greeting"></p>
            <h1 id="racenumber"></h1>
            <p id="startTime"></p>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script>
        // initialize variables

        // saving the input values
        function save() {
            let nameValue = document.getElementById('fullName').value
            let ageValue = document.getElementById('age').value
            let timeValue = document.getElementById('time').value
            console.log(`Name: ${nameValue} Age: ${ageValue} Time of Registration: ${timeValue}`);

            // getting the variables for display
            let greetingDisplay = document.getElementById('greeting');
            let raceNumberDisplay = document.getElementById('racenumber');
            let startTimeDisplay = document.getElementById('startTime');

            // LOGIC FOR THE NUMBER ASSIGNMENT
            let raceNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
            

            // specify the text in the greeting element
            let greetingText = `Hello, ${nameValue}! Your race number is`;

            // display the values entered by the user
            greetingDisplay.innerText = greetingText;
            raceNumberDisplay.innerText = 4;
            startTimeDisplay.innerText = "5:40 PM";
        }  
    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your actual problem?  The flippant way to answer your question is "yes, you can use if else statements", but I'm confident that's not what you're actually looking for.

Comment: according to MDN "The value of the time input is always in 24-hour format that includes leading zeros: hh:mm, regardless of the input format". with that considered, you can simply get rid of the semicolon and parse the value as integer, like `parseInt("14:16".replace(':',''))` that will result in the integer number `1416` which can be compared to any other time value formatted in the same way

Comment: in your example, "registrationTime > 7:30", if I register now it would be: `if ( parseInt("14:26".replace(':','')) > parseInt("07:30".replace(':',''))  )` this "translates" into `if (1426 > 730)`

Comment: You _can_ compare date or time values in _string_ form, if all the parts are "same-width" in each of the two values, and properly ordered - because string comparison happens character by character, from left to right. So you can "compare" f.e. `2022-01-05` and `2022-02-15`, or `07:30` and `12:15`, using `==`, `>=` or `<=`. It will of course not work to compare `7:30` to `12:15`, and not for `15.02.2022` vs `05.01.2022` either.